# Querying Parse class to get top N objects sorted by certain field from groups of objects matched by another field?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

Sorry if this was answered here or on the docs before, I did a search but hadn't encountered an answer yet. I'm using Unity Parse SDK. The idea gets is a bit verbose when I describe it straight on, so I'll start with an illustration. Imagine a simple leaderboard divided into several activities and displaying N top times per activity:

[leaderboard illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf9ty.jpg)

Let's say I have a set of Result objects stored in Parse DB, containing activityID and time fields (and fluff fields like user names, but those are irrelevant). I want to set up a query that will return only, say, five Result objects per activityID, with the smallest time across that activityID and sorted by that time. If we are to follow UI mockup from above, a desired array I'd like to get from a query would potentially look like this:

```
0  | activityID: 0 | time: 43
1  | activityID: 0 | time: 72
2  | activityID: 0 | time: 81
3  | activityID: 0 | time: 92
4  | activityID: 0 | time: 97
5  | activityID: 1 | time: 12
6  | activityID: 1 | time: 42

...

13 | activityID: 2 | time: 49
14 | activityID: 2 | time: 52
```

After [studying the related docs](https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#queries), the stumbling block for me is not knowing how to limit queries in any other way but this:

```
query = query.Limit (n);
```

Ideally, I want to split all Results in the Parse DB into separate groups by their activityID value, and only then perform sorting by time on those groups, and only then perform trimming to N, and only then return the query response consisting of (N * number of activity types) objects. With LINQ, I could probably get that result with the following expression:

```
LeaderboardResults.GroupBy(x => activityID).SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(x => x.time).Take(N));
```

Except I have to use Parse methods and syntax, and I'm not sure how to get the same result from them. The undesirable request I mentioned in the bottom right of the illustration can be formulated like this:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Result").OrderBy ("activityID").ThenBy ("time");
var queryTask = query.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (t =>
{
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
    // do stuff with query results
}
```

This will simply dump every single Result in existence to the client, which is not okay. Using query.Limit (n) I mentioned above is not right either, that will just dump every single result from first and subsequent activities until object count limit runs out, while we want at least an even object count returned per activity.

Obviously, it's possible to just issue multiple requests with Where to get separate per-activity arrays of results on the client side, but as you can imagine that's a horrifying solution in terms of backend load and in terms of client performance. Ideally I need just one query returning an array of (leaderboard size * activity type count) sorted objects.

So how can I achieve this? I feel like I'm missing a simple piece of a puzzle.

Comment: Damn son, is all that wall of text and massive image necessary to your problem?

Comment: Image goes straight to the point with a short question and expected result depicted on it. Rest of the post simply clarifies things in detail in case that can help someone with an answer.